# How come beta sites don't count as 100 rep bonus

Tags: support, linked-accounts

I don't know if this is a bug but how come on beta sites such as Wordpress Answers, Apple and Code Review don't count as 100 rep bonus.

I have well over 200 rep here on Meta and other sites but how come I don't get the 100 rep bonus on beta site public or privite.

I know there might be a issue with users claiming that 100 rep bonus on startup but I don't see why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to unassociate and re-associate if you did not have +200 rep at the time of original association -- otherwise you don't get the bonus.

Comment: sorry I did that 2 secs earlier and then went on the sites and I got them Thanks!